# How to import point data from python to postreSQL database?

Tags: python, sql, insert, geometry, point

I have a dataframe `df` with one column called "geom" among the others. It consists of longitude, latitude coordinates:

e.g. `POINT (10.1768627166748 50.1768627166748)`

I tried to import this single column data to the corresponding column of my database in postreSQL using the following command.

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
df['geom'].to_sql("...", engine, schema='...', if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326)})
```

However, I get this error:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Please note that `id` is the primary key of the database. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an "id" column to the dataframe and give it a unique value, currently you're trying to insert null into the pk field:

```
# add column
df['id'] = 1234 
# Observe the result 
df
# insert entire df (not just geom column)
df.to_sql("...", engin ...
```

Make sure you insert the entire dataframe (not just the geom column).

Comment: Thank you for your response @PetArbiter. When I actually try to import the whole df I get this error: ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Point'

Comment: interesting, so psycopg2 doesn't like point??
I don't have Postgres installed right now to recreate your issue, i can think of a couple of workarounds though: create the id field with an identity column (constraint GENERATED AS IDENTITY) so you don't have to insert an id (it will auto increment an integer), or possibly break you POINT field back into lat/long columns and insert that df (not ideal i know).